# Аннотация Psalm для типа возвращаемого значения в месте вызова метода/функции

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ, статический-анализ, linter, hint

Для демонстрации проблемы есть такой упрощенный реальный код:

```
abstract class A
{
    /**
     * @var array<string, mixed>
     */
    private array $params;

    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        static::validateParams($params);
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    final protected function getParamByKey(string $key): mixed
    {
        return $this->params[$key];
    }

    /**
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    abstract protected static function validateParams(array $params): void;
}

final class B extends A
{
    protected static function validateParams(array $params): void
    {
        if (!is_string($params['X'])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Param X must be string');
        }
        if (!is_int($params['Y'])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Param Y must be int');
        }
    }

    public function getParamX(): string
    {
        return $this->getParamByKey('X');
    }

    public function getParamY(): int
    {
        return $this->getParamByKey('Y');
    }
}
```

Теперь к сути. При прогоне этого кода через psalm для методов `B::getParamX` и `B::getParamY` я получаю по два варнинга: ***MixedReturnStatement: Could not infer a return type*** и ***MixedInferredReturnType: Could not verify return type 'string' for***. Понятно что причина в том, что в объявлении метода `getParamByKey`, mixed указан как тип возвращаемого значения, из-за чего psalm делает вывод, что в `B::getParamX` и `B::getParamY` могут прилететь данные любого типа. Только вот в действительности это не так, поскольку перед вызовами `B::getParamX` и `B::getParamY` вызывается метод `A::validateParams`, который гарантирует корректность типов для обоих методов.

Вопрос: какую аннотацию можно задать, чтобы заставить psalm корректно выводить типы с учетом вызова `A::validateParams`?
Если так сделать нельзя, то можно ли в месте вызова `$this->getParamByKey` указать возвращаемый тип из `getParamByKey`? Чтобы это выглядело как-то так:

```
public function getParamX(): string
{
    return $this->getParamByKey('X'); /** @psalm-return string */
}

public function getParamY(): int
{
    return $this->getParamByKey('Y'); /** @psalm-return int */
}
```

Тут конечно можно создать переменную, присвоить ей возвращаемое значение, а потом задать ей аннотацию `/** @var string $tmp **/`, только мне этот вариант не нравится, так как выглядит не очень красиво.